# Extract specific data with specific output with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to extract a specified values, but doesn't work.

The HTML code is the next:

```
<body style="background: #FFF; padding-left: 5px;">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="verify()" id="form1">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/asdasfafasf/9Q2w==" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAwKb/LCHCALs0bLrBgKM54rGBulKe8VRM9SNhTfqyz0GubMFea7i" />
        </div>
        <div class="nicer">
            <input name="TextBox1" type="text" value="asdf44" id="TextBox1" placeholder="Ingresa tu patente" />
        </div>
        <p class="sample">
            <br /> sample: asdasd34 &oacute; ABCD12
            <br /> Para . Ej. AB<strong style="font-weight: bold !importand;">0</strong>123</p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Consultar" id="Button1" class="button orange_btn small_btn" />
        </p>
        <h3><span id="Label1" class="infractions_report">result: asdf44</span></h3>
        <div>
            <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">date</th>
                    <th scope="col">category</th>
                    <th scope="col">statusok</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="txt">
                    <td>10-08-2015</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>cs nor</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="txt">
                    <td>04-08-2015</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>cs nor2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="txt">
                    <td>01-08-2015</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>cs nor3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="txt">
                    <td>30-07-2015</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>cs nor4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="txt">
                    <td>19-06-2015</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>cn nor5</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The PHP code is the next:

```
$expresiondate = '/\<tr\>[\s]*\<td class\=\"txt\"\>[\s]*([^\s\<\/]*)/is';
preg_match_all($expresiondate , $buffer, $exit1);

$expresionCategory= '/\-[\d]{4}[\s]*<\/td\>[\s]*\<td class\=\"txt\"\>[\s]*([^\s\<\/]*)/is';
preg_match_all($expresionCategory, $buffer, $exit2);

$expresionstatus= '/\>[\s]*[\d]*[\s]*<\/td\>[\s]*\<td class\=\"txt\"\>[\s]*([^\s\<\/]*)/is';
preg_match_all($expresionstatus, $buffer, $exit3);
```

And the result I need is the next (example values, but this output):

```
    1. date: 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '<td align="center">15/01/2016 00:22:16</td>',
    1 => '<td align="center">16/01/2016 00:22:16</td>',
    2 => '<td align="center">11/01/2015 00:22:16</td>',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '15/01/2016',
    1 => '16/01/2016',
    2 => '11/01/2015',
  ),
)

2. category
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '<td>10-08-2015</td><td>1</td><td>cs nor</td>',
    1 => '<td>10-08-2015</td><td>1</td><td>cs nor</td>',
    2 => '<td>10-08-2015</td><td>1</td><td>cs nor</td>',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '1',
  ),
)

3.status
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '<td>10-08-2015</td><td>1</td><td>cs nor</td>',
    1 => '<td>10-08-2015</td><td>1</td><td>cs nor</td>',
    2 => '<td>10-08-2015</td><td>1</td><td>cs nor</td>',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'cn nor1',
    1 => 'cn nor2',
    2 => 'cn nor3,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are hard to explain..

I would suggest to use "named capturing groups" to scrape the content from the table cells.

I came up with the following regexp:

```
$regexp = "/<td>(?P<data>(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}))<\/td>\s+<td>(?P<category>\d{1})<\/td>\s+<td>(?P<status>.*)<\/td>/mi";
preg_match_all($regexp, $input_lines, $matches);
```

That thing might look overwhelming at first sight, but its constructed by parts.

Ok, lets go through this one by one:

- a capturing group starts with `(?P<name_of_the_capturing_group>(regexp))`

  - where regexp is the part you want to capture for that group
- you want to capture the content inside the td tag, so one places the group inside the td
- each td tag is followed by spaces `\s+`
- now the 3 regexp parts for the capturing groups

  - date `(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})`

    - matches: two digits minus two digits minus 4 digits
    - capturing group = `(?P<date>(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}))`
  - category `\d{1}`

    - just a single digit
    - capturing group= `(?P<category>\d{1})`
  - status `.*`

    - match all, mixed
    - capturing group = `(?P<status>.*)`

After running `preg_match_all` just `var_dump($matches);` it should contain keys for date, category and status.

Always remember: Only Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex.

Comment: pd i can parse html whit regex ;) look > /\<tr class\=\"txt\"\>\s*<td>(.*?)<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td>/mi

Comment: ;) glad i could help a bit

Answer (score 0):

One more time, regex are not the tool to parse HTML. Use the build-in tools `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` that are designed for.

```
$url = 'page.html';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$rowNodeList = $xp->query('//table[@id="GridView1"]/tr[@class="txt"]');
$results = [];
foreach ($rowNodeList as $rowNode) {
    $colNodeList = $rowNode->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $results[] = [ 'date'     => $colNodeList->item(0)->nodeValue,
                   'category' => $colNodeList->item(1)->nodeValue, 
                   'status'   => $colNodeList->item(2)->nodeValue ];
}

libxml_clear_errors();

print_r($results);
```